# Best proxy debugger

Tags: debugging, proxy

What is the best proxy debugger for windows or debian?

Comment: To say what's "best" requires knowing which features you need, which features you want, and what features you don't care about.

Comment: What does "best" mean?  Cheapest?  Most memory use?  Largest .EXE file?

Answer (score 1):

On windows, I use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for HTTP(S), which hooks up quite well with Firefox.
For lower level debugging I've used [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Generally I tend to use [YATT](http://www.pocketsoap.com/yatt/) - its simple and works well for me.