# How to log HTTP requests made from Qt QML OSM map plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, qml, openstreetmap

I'm building a Qt 5.11 application which embeds an openstreetmap QML component. Everything works fine but I need to be able to log HTTP requests for a debugging purposes.
I can't find anything in the [Map documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtlocation-map.html). Nothing else in the [OSM plugin documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/location-plugin-osm.html).

I took a look at the geoservice plugin sources. Nothing.

Is there another way to do what I need?

Edit: I can't accept a solution which implies to modify Qt sources because it will complicate build and deployment.

Comment: You probably want an HTTP proxy debugger. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384434/best-proxy-debugger

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, this is not only for debugging purposes on the developer's machine, but also for end users. They don't always have a proxy, and I would like to embed these requests in my application logs.